# How to monitor get/post endpoints on aws api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, monitoring, high-availability, api-gateway

I have got a service stack consisting of:

api gateway ( with custom url )
    |
  lambda

The endpoint is public and will be hit by customer. Now, the question is, How do I ensure that endpoint is up and running? Of course, api gateway and lambda are highly available but still couple of things could go wrong. e.g. bad deploy, api gateway itself is down.

Is there 3rd party service that provide monitoring for endpoint with passing headers? Is there open source solution for this?

Comment: Cloudwatch should help you here https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/

Comment: How? Please point me to a documentation. Cloudwatch is huge.

Comment: Try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/monitoring_automated_manual.html